# JAXB creating empty objects

Tags: java, jaxb, classcastexception

I have an XML based on XSD. The xsd is

```
<xs:complexType name="objectOneType" mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="nestedObject" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="attribute" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Now, when i receive this XML

```
<xmlresponse>
  <xmlrequest>
    <objectone attribute="changed" />
  </xmlrequest>
  <xmlsrc>
    <objectone attribute="changed" />
  </xmlsrc>
</xmlresponse>
```

In this XML, the object **OBjECTONE** doesn't have an object named **NESTEDOBJECT**. now instead of ignoring it, it is inserting a an *empty* object in **OBJECTONE** which is of **STRING** type. so when my code tries to process **OBJECTONE** assuming it has an object type **NESTEDOBJECT**. It throws classcast exception.

Any idea?

P.S: Kill me sicne i am using JAXB 1.2

Comment: probably a stupid remark, but, in your xsd you define a complex type named "objectOneType", while your xml has "objectone" objects...

Comment: I changed the xml from original to post here on stackoverflow. the original xml/xsd doesn't have these problems. the xml response is properly being validated against the XSD at http://tools.decisionsoft.com/schemaValidate/results.jsp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is the annotation `mixed="true"`. With this annotation structures like

```
<content>
  <italic>Italic</italic> ist not <underline>underline</underline>
</content>
```

are possible. Internally JAXB creates a `List<Object> insideContent` which would be in the upper case classes of: `String`, `Italic`, `String`, `Underline` and `String`. I assume that you output your XML with something like `Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT` which inserts a newline and tabulator for the **formatted output**. You can either:

- Don't use formatted output: `<content><italic>This</italic> is a <underline>test</underline></content>` should not have a leading or trailing `String`
- Don't use `mixed="true"`
- Test your child class with `instanceOf` while iterating the `List<Object>`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I will try to ask other team to change the schema. Meanwhile, could you tell me what side effects **instanceof** might have specific to this use-case. I am alraedy using this check. Reason for asking this question here was that since i dun know much about JAXB I wanted to make sure if my approach is okay or not.

Comment: For some use-cases I also have the `mixed="true"` and I'm not aware of any negative side effects using `instanceOf`. Due to the fact that `instanceOf` is  is not a call but a JVM opcode, you can't get it faster than that.